# Rails exception: No route matches [GET] "/clock_events/1/clock_in"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

It used to work but after some changes, Action Controller is catching an exception
`Routing Error: No route matches [GET] "/clock_events/1/clock_in"`

`routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'clock_events#index'

  get '/register', to: 'users#new'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :clock_events, except: [:destroy] do
    member do
      post 'clock_in', to: 'clocks#clock_in'
      post 'clock_out', to: 'clocks#clock_out'
    end
  end

  resources :users, except: [:destroy]

end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `clock_in` with the `post` http verb, here:

```
resources :clock_events, except: [:destroy] do
  member do
    post 'clock_in', to: 'clocks#clock_in'
    post 'clock_out', to: 'clocks#clock_out'
  end
end
```

But, you're trying to use the `get` verb, as indicated here:

```
Routing Error: No route matches [GET] "/clock_events/1/clock_in"
```

You need to either change your path to use the `get` verb:

```
resources :clock_events, except: [:destroy] do
  member do
    get 'clock_in', to: 'clocks#clock_in'
    post 'clock_out', to: 'clocks#clock_out'
  end
end
```

Or modify your link (or whatever) to use the `post` method.

Also, your `clock_in` and `clock_out` actions are called on the `clocks` controller, not the `clock_events` controller, as indicated by your `to:` directive:

```
resources :clock_events, except: [:destroy] do
  member do
    post 'clock_in', to: 'clocks#clock_in'
    post 'clock_out', to: 'clocks#clock_out'
  end
end
```

Are you sure you don't want to use the `ClockEventsController`? If so, you could do:

```
resources :clock_events, except: [:destroy] do
  member do
    post :clock_in
    post :clock_out
  end
end
```

In which case you would get:

```
 clock_in_clock_event POST   /clock_events/:id/clock_in(.:format)      clock_events#clock_in
clock_out_clock_event POST   /clock_events/:id/clock_out(.:format)     clock_events#clock_out
         clock_events GET    /clock_events(.:format)                   clock_events#index
                      POST   /clock_events(.:format)                   clock_events#create
      new_clock_event GET    /clock_events/new(.:format)               clock_events#new
     edit_clock_event GET    /clock_events/:id/edit(.:format)          clock_events#edit
          clock_event GET    /clock_events/:id(.:format)               clock_events#show
                      PATCH  /clock_events/:id(.:format)               clock_events#update
                      PUT    /clock_events/:id(.:format)               clock_events#update
```